# Parity Bit Checking

Tags: system

Would anyone know how to even start on a problem like this? I don't understand how to fill out the table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EqP9.png)

Comment: this is not homework help site. at least try a few things, and let us know where you got stuck, add some code and so on.

Comment: also, the image is not displaying :) you will need to edit and format image display. try and give some context like which language you are using, and try to google some basic info. you are new here, but once you start these things, you will have better questions and faster community help.